# Can subsonic build for me the CRUD and paging stored procedures?

Tags: .net, database, stored-procedures, subsonic

Can subsonic help me building these main stored procedures?

Can i edit its template to make it generate these SPs?

Where to begin learning that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as version 2 is concerned you could probably edit the templates to generate your SP creation scripts but it would be a far from trivial task. And of course you'd then have to add the functionality to execute the scripts, cleaning up previous generated SPs and ensuring you didn't drop any others. To be honest I would advise against it as SubSonic is designed to generate .Net code based on your DB.

With version 3 of SubSonic and all the power of t4 you could add the functionality a lot more easily, however once you've got the full Linq support in version 3 you don't need SPs for paging and I can't see a reason to generate SPs instead of using Linq itself.

Comment: Linq is too much slow than SPs

Comment: That depends, for simple CRUD you're not going to see any major performance difference between the straight SQL generated from LINQ and an SP. What would you want your generated SPs to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use SPs then something like Codesmith is a better choice. You can build out your own SP generators using T4 - but it's just an extra layer of fluff when it comes to stuff Subsonic can do you for you.

Up to you and how you design things - but SPs have sort of lost their shine. And no - Linq is not slower than SPs. In fact there is no perf gain from SPs at all.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, seams that i will go with LINQ, as it seams that everyone convince me to go with :).